# Cannot set the expire date of a cookie

Tags: javascript, django, cookies, request

I'm developing an web application with `ReactJS` and a `Django` web API. My problem is:

I send a request to the API, that returns me a token, that I'll use to send requests that needs authentication, and a expire date for the token.

The response is something like:

```
{
   name: "Elliot",
   id: 1,
   token: "<the token here>"
   expires: "2018-04-29T17:00:00.000Z"
}
```

Then, when I try to do this:

```
document.cookie = `token=${response.token};expires=${response.expires}`
```

It sets the expire date to the year of 1969. Does anyone know why?

Details:

- I took a look if the date isn't already expired, but, it's not. It's always 3 hours from now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved! I thought that the date was on the right format, but it wasn't. Then, I converted the date using `toUTCString()`, like this:

```
const expires = new Date(response.expires)
document.cookie = `token=${response.token};expires=${expires.toUTCString()}`
```

Hope it helps somebody else!